# Copy the 1st Data [related to values]to same column

Tags: excel

I am making this shop Data, Where I need to write the order time for receipt date.
Reciept Number is 464 and you can see its time 18:15:45 (1st time) , Now I can just copy and paste the same time for all 464 . 
But the problem is I have 1000+ Datas in single day and I need to do for 1 week Data. So is there any formulas or excel trick I can do it flawlessly?
I hate attached a screenshot .
[1st Date Order with Same Receipt Number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrIUN.png)

[More Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFZyP.png)

Comment: have you try `autofilter`?

Comment: Can you be more specify?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column of `Receipt Number` is `C` and the column of `Time` is `B`. Enter the following code in to B2 and copy and paste it to the rest of column `B`.

```
=IF(MATCH(C2,C:C,0)=ROW(C2),"",INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,C:C,0)))
```

The cells should appear empty at first, but as soon as you enter a time in the FIRST cell with a `Receipt Number`, all the other cells with the same `Receipt Number` should change automatically.

**Edit**:
According to the new image,  `Receipt Number` is column  `E` and  `Time` is column  `B`. And luckily column `B` is increasing. To generate column  `D`, simply enter the following code in to `D2` and copy and paste it to the rest of column `D`.

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,E:E,0))
```

Comment: I already have time on Column B. Its from log. I have created new column D , for "Order Time" Column E is Receipt Number . Order Time = Column B 1st time of for same receipt number. I have added more picture on main post. Can you please take a look at it.

Comment: @FplNepal See my changes.